# Open popup after form submit in php/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to configure send.php file so that it triggers a hidden popup(look at the HIDDEN section, #modal_success) after form submit. At this point, it only sends data from forms on my email, but the popup with the "success" message won't show. Please help. Thank you

This is the `send.php` file

```php
<?php
$to = "mail@mail.com";
$tema = "New request"; 
$message = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br>";
$message .= "E-mail: ".$_POST['email']."<br>"; 
$message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."<br>";
$message .= "Form: ".$_POST['form']."<br>"; 
$message .= "Where: ".$_POST['where']."<br>";
$message .= "Square: ".$_POST['square']."<br>"; 
$message .= "Price: ".$_POST['price']."<br>"; 
$message .= "When: ".$_POST['when']."<br>"; 
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
isset($_POST['agree']);
if(mail($to, $tema, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'success';
}  
else {
    echo 'error';
};
?>
```

This is JavaScript file

```js
// MODAL

$('.modalshow').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var 
    $href = $(this).attr('href'),
    $form = $(this).attr('data-form');
    if($form) {
        $($href).find('input[name="form"]').val($form);
    }

    $.fancybox.open({
        src  : $href,
        type : 'inline',
        afterLoad : function() {
            window.quizSlider.update();
        }
    });
})
$(document).on('click', '.fmodal', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.fancybox.open( $($href+' a'), {});
})  
    // # MODAL

// FORM SUBMIT

$('.form').on('submit', function () {
  var
    $form = $(this),
    $name = $form.find('input[name="name"]'),
    $phone = $form.find('input[name="phone"]'),
    $email = $form.find('input[name="email"]'),
    $agree = $form.find('input[name="agree"]:checked'),
    $rv_email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/,
    $error = false;

  if ($form.hasClass('form__file')) {
    var $data = new FormData();
    if ($name.length) {
      $data.append('name', $name.val());
    }
    if ($phone.length) {
      $data.append('phone', $phone.val());
    }
    if ($email.length) {
      $data.append('email', $email.val());
    }
  } else {
    var $data = $form.serialize();
  }


  if ($form.find('input[name="agree"]').length && !$agree.length) {
    $form.find('.agree__cont').addClass('invalid');
    $error = true;
  } else {
    $form.find('.agree__cont').removeClass('invalid');
  }

  if ($name.length) {
    if ($name.val().length < 3) {
      $name.addClass('invalid');
      $error = true;
    } else {
      $name.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }
  if ($phone.length) {
    if ($phone.val().length < 1) {
      $phone.addClass('invalid');
      $error = true;
    } else {
      $phone.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }
  if ($email.length) {
    if ($email.val().length < 1 || !$rv_email.test($email.val())) {
      $email.addClass('invalid');
      $error = true;
    } else {
      $email.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  }

  if ($error) {
    return false;
  } else {
    if ($form.hasClass('form__file')) {
      if ($form.find('input[name="file"]').length) {
        $data.append("file", $form.find('input[name="file"]')[0].files[0]);
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./send.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function ($json) {

        },
        success: function ($json) {
          if ($json['success']) {

            $instance = $.fancybox.getInstance();
            if ($instance) { $instance.close(); }
            $.fancybox.open({
              src: $('#modal_success'),
              type: 'inline'
            });
          }
        },
        error: function (json) {
          console.log(json);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./send.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $data,
        beforeSend: function ($json) {

        },
        success: function ($json) {
          if ($json['success']) {

            $instance = $.fancybox.getInstance();
            if ($instance) { $instance.close(); }
            $.fancybox.open({
              src: $('#modal_success'),
              type: 'inline'
            });
          }
        },
        error: function (json) {
          console.log(json);
        }
      });
    }

  }
  return false;
})
        // # FORM SUBMIT
```

This is HTML part on my page

```html
<!-- HIDDEN -->

<div id="modal_success" class="modal__item success__modal">
  <div class="modal__title">Thank you! Your request has been sent!</div>
  <div class="success__text">we will contact you shortly</div>
</div>

<!-- # HIDDEN -->
```

Comment: You should return success with parameter and check $json['success'] == 'success' then show popup

Comment: try $('#myModal').modal('show');

Comment: @ForgeWebDesign could you please help me to implement this. how specifically should i modify the send.php file. thanks

Comment: @user39404 this will NOT be in the send.php; you must add the changes to your AJAX in the JavaScript. Basically, upon success, you will want to show the pop-up with the proper details.

Comment: @Twisty i added "//modal" section in JavaScript file. please take a look. also i've been told that i just have to adjust send.php file to get it to work